# Removing some buttons in Ember-leaflet-draw

Tags: javascript, ember.js, leaflet

I want to remove the buttons that is shown in the UI like the ones used to draw lines,circles,polygons.
I simple used leaflet draw in my ember application like

template.hbs

```
{{#leaflet-map
onLoad=(action 'initMap')
onClick=(route-action 'getLatLng')
lat=lat
lng=lng
zoom=zoom
class='leaflet_map'}}
{{draw-control  position="topright" showDrawingLayer='true'}}
{{/leaflet-map}}
```

Now, is there any way of removing some buttons that i don't want from the UI? I did find the following code which seems like what im looking for but how to use it in emberjs?

```
 var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
     draw: {
         polygon: false,
         marker: false
     },
     edit: {
         featureGroup: editableLayers,
         edit: false
     }
 });
```

Comment: Turns out i had been looking for a complex solution when there was an easier one.I just changed the CSS of the buttons in the toolbar :D

`.leaflet-touch .leaflet-draw-toolbar .leaflet-draw-draw-marker ,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-draw-toolbar .leaflet-draw-draw-circle ,
{
    display: none;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying CSS is not a good practice :)

Just set drawOptions to `{{draw-control}}` helper as:

```
{{draw-control
    draw=drawOptions
}}
```

and customize your drawOptions in your component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
...
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    ...
    drawOptions: {
        circle: false,
        rectangle: false,
        polygon: false,
    },
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks but i couldn't come up with anything else :D and that was my last ditch effort.